# C# SSL Stops Receiving (But Connection doesn't break)

Tags: c#, sockets, ssl

I have a game server system that has a sslstream module and reads/writes using async calls. The server holds up great, functions perfectly fine, however, after a period of increased traffic the user's SSL simply stops receiving on the server end.

However, the client still gets sent data, and sends data fine, for them it seems like the game still works fine for them until they can't deal damage.

No other users are directly effected at the time, all other streams continue along (unless they also hit the same bug), resetting the connection will restore the to a functioning state.

As far as I can tell from debugging:

- The Socket remains active (Until the server initiates an inactivity drop)
- Only Server side receiving is ever effected
- Increasing the amount of data sent does increase the likelihood of the issue occuring
- No Exceptions are thrown, the stream still shows an ability to read/write
- The stream can still successfully send to the client
- Terminating the client's connection will send through the normal 0 length termination 'read' on the client

Does anyone know what would cause this? (also possibly worthy of note, the system also can be booted up with a straight TCP socket, and it runs flawlessly with that. The issue only occurs when using the SSL stream)

Comment: You can run a communications trace to see this, but also you can determine if there are half-sessions which indicate the TCP stack is too busy. The command to do that is via a dos prompt and is named netstat.  Half-sessions show up as xyz-wait.  What you reported is possibly an overburdened TCP/IP stack which is bullet proof.  If it can't process something it just sits on the queue until it can process it.  The other side attempts to keep the session open up to 10 times which only exacerbates the situation.

Comment: Please try to post some code. Maybe you can reproduce with something smaller than your full code base?